# *error TS1003: Identifier expected

Tags: angular-calendar

I am following this tutorial [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-calendar-scheduler#install) for an angular calender app. I am stuck in an error that contains this error in the compille time: 
  **error TS1003: Identifier expected.** when i try to import

`import { ... } from 'angular-calendar-scheduler';`.

I dont know what is the problem.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Replace dots with actual import entities names.

Comment: I dont know what are the actual entities for this import.

Comment: You do. Everything that's unresolved will be your entities. Quick look to their demo shows types like `CalendarPeriod`, `CalendarSchedulerEventAction`, `CalendarSchedulerEvent` and some others.